# Selenium cannot click Sign in button on amazon.com

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on sign in button for amazon and used the following different locators (as advised ). There is no error message and button is not clicked. Can anyone please advise?

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']/span[1]"));`

OR:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Hello. Sign in')]"));`

OR:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'nav-line-1')]"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
try { 
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element); 
    actions.moveToElement(element).perform();
    actions.click(element).perform();
} catch (Exception e) { }`

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the html that is represented in your locators?

Answer (score 1):

You are choosing the incorrect locators on the webpage to select the Sign In option. Also you should be using the move to element methods that the action class provides you, in order to hover over the menu and then bring the Sign In options visible.

Go to the element with id `nav-link-accountList` using the `findElement()` and then you can do something like this

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement mainMenu = 
driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList"));
actions.moveToElement(mainMenu);
actions.build().perform();

WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.nav-action-inner"));
actions.moveToElement(subMenu);
actions.click().build().perform();
```

This should do the trick. PS - My Java is not the best, so please take a look at the Java syntax side to see if there are any errors.

Comment: The Sign In option is getting visible , but it is not getting clicked.